# I need to insert a total at the bottom of a dynamic table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, sum

I am having some issues with my VBA code that will select data from one sheet, copy it, paste it to a new sheet and insert a total at the bottom of the table. The first steps work, but I am struggling with the total , any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Range("A3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone     _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks     _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Pricing Main'!RC[1]"
    Range(xlToRight, xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-36]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'youre struggling with' the total? does it show up? is it incorrect...?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in making formula with dynamic range (while first row is always the same and the 2nd is different), you could use:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R[-1]C)"
```

If you're using number without "[]" it will absolute address with $
In this example it will be ="SUM(A1:Ax)" where X is row before active cell

Another option is using Activecell.Formula and get this address by combining letters with Activecell.row

```
activecell.Formula = "=SUM(A1:A" & activecell.Row - 1 &")"
```

And after that you can autofill to other columns if needed by

```
activecell.AutoFill Destination:=range(activecell, activecell.Offset(0,5)), Type:=xlfilldefault
```

3rd option could be using range variables calculate address before formula:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim rng1 As Range Dim rng2 As Range Dim rng3 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1") Set rng2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Set rng3 = Range(rng1, rng2)

ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & rng3.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

If you have another problem, please, try explain it better ;)